# Selecting newest id result where column is relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the code below where I select profile_picture from the column relation where the userID is 129, how ever I tried adding where id is max and realised that rules out selecting from only rows that contain profile_picture.

I need the query to select from media where relation is profile_picture and id = 129 and the max id for profile_picture

```html
SELECT * FROM media WHERE userID = 129 AND relation = 'profile_picture' AND id=(
    SELECT max(id) FROM media.relation
    )
```

Comment: sample data and expected output will be great, and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information provided, I am guessing you almost have it right; you just need to move the WHERE (except the id part of course) to the subquery. (And fix that `media.relation` to just `media` I would guess).

```
SELECT * 
FROM media 
WHERE id = (
   SELECT max(id) 
   FROM media 
   WHERE userID = 129 AND relation = 'profile_picture'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT and ordering:

```
SELECT * 
FROM media 
WHERE userID = 129 AND relation = 'profile_picture'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: TOP doesnt seem to be a valid sql / mysql statement :/

Comment: TOP works in SQL Server, MySQL has LIMIT. I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, yep just tested and all working, thank you :)